# What does it mean to be “in black”

Tags: meaning

Listening to several songs of late musician Amy Winehouse she often sings the word *black*.  For example in the song *Back to black*

> I'll go back to black

Similar in the song *Rehab* she sings:

> Yes, I been black but when I come back [..]

What does *black* mean? I assume it means something like “depressed”/“depression”?

Is this a phrase that is commonly used in English - or is it a “made up term”? Would people understand the meaning if used in a real sentence?

Answer (score 0):

**Trying something out, but realizing it wasn't for you, and going back to what you know**. It is also like you said, **sorrowful**. Rehab is talking about Amy plays on the phrase “once you go black you don’t go back”. She went through a very dark time involving tumultuous relationships and drug abuse.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. *Going to black* usually refers to drinking, drug use, and depression.

I found a very nice annotation on genius.com:

> Black is a metaphor for depression. When in a depressive state, everything seems black and dark. Winehouse was known to suffer from depression from a young age.
>
> Black is also often associated with death, so this may indicative of the singer coming to terms with the “death” of the relationship – a mourning of sorts. This coincides with the music video, where the singer attends a funeral.
>
> “Black” is also the end result of her drinking. In attempting to escape from depression brought by her boyfriend, she blacks out.
>
> ‘Back to black’ may also allude to returning to heroin use (i.e. black tar heroin), in which case ‘troubled track’ from two lines previous is suggestive of track marks that remain from injecting heroin.

Answer (score 0):

The particular expression "back to black" is a metaphor, created by Amy, for that song.

The figurative use of "black" or "dark" related to depression is idiomatic.

We say "A black mood" to mean feeling depressed, irritable and short-tempered. Compare this with "feeling blue" - a much calmer sort of sadness, with no anger.

A "Black day" is a day of tragedy.  "6 February 1958 was a black day for Manchester United Football club as many of the first team died in an aeroplane crash."

On the other hand the expressions "I'll go back to black" and "I've been black" are not idiomatic and are poetic creations of Amy.